# Showing the actual value of complex type parameter with NUnit in the reports

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am stuck at finding one functionality that NUnit provides which I almost certain that I saw it before and I thought myself I will use it, but sadly I didn't pin it somewhere.

We are writing our tests like so:

```
[Test]
public void Post_StakeToDifferetnSelectionsViaBetsBetIdEndpoint_ReturnsCorrectData(
        [ValueSource(typeof(JsonContextCache), nameof(JsonContextCache.RandomThreeUniqueSelecionIds))] string[] selectionIds,
        [ValueSource(typeof(TestData), nameof(TestData.OddStyles))] OddStyle oddStyle, 
        [Values(true, false)] bool logged)
```

Problem with this approach is that when we supply `ValueSource` or `TestCaseSource` attributes with complex types (like `string[]`, custom types) results in our CI environments from NUnit are like so:

```
Post_StakeToDifferetnSelectionsViaBetsBetIdEndpoint_ReturnsCorrectData(System.String[],European,True)
```

What I want is, instead of this `System.String[]` to show the array values, but I don't know how can I make Nunit do that for me.

Comment: Show your code for `JsonContextCache.RandomThreeUniqueSelecionIds`. There you should provide an array of strings which you can then access in your test-method. If you want a single id, then provide a single string instead of an array.

Comment: I dont want single string, I want to keep it as it is, but show the actual value of the parameter instead of the type.

Comment: Well, is providing an *array of string* one *single* test, or actually a *set of test-cases*? Do you want the test-method to be executed once or once per element within your array?

Comment: I want to be executed once. And the result to be `MethodName(["1","2"],European,True)`

Comment: Then show what you´re doing with the array within your test-method.

Comment: Why does this matter I don't understand? This is related to how NUnit builds its reports, not how I handle my case

Comment: Nunit will do what *any* framework will do in order to write something to a console, file or whatever: call `ToString` on that type. In your case `myArrayOfStrings.ToString()` will just return `System.string[]`.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but I am almost sure that there was a way of telling NUnit how this complex type should be build in the reports...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

It's not possible in your situation, because you are using `[TestCaseSource]`, which leaves it entirely up to NUnit to assemble the test cases and name them. There are workarounds, but they are rather inconvenient.

Longer answer, edited from https:github.com/nunit/docs/issues/244:

You can change the naming of **individual** test cases in NUnit in certain circumstances:
1. When using the `[TestCase]` attribute, by specifying the `SetName` property.
2. When using the `[TestCaseSource]` attribute, provided the arguments are given by use of `TestCaseData` instances. Again, the property to use is `SetName`.

Two drawbacks to the above:
1. You have to do it one test at a time.
2. It isn't available at all when specifying arguments  using `[Values]` or `[ValueSource]`.

The general solution that NUnit has always historically advised is to override `ToString` in the types you are using as arguments. Obviously, when the type is `string[]` that's not available to you as an option.

Unfortunately, unless we implement a fix to the above issue, there's no good alternative for your case. Workarounds to consider:

1. Use `[TestCase]` or `[TestCaseSource]`, spelling out all the combinations yourself, and specify `SetName` on each case.
2. Wrap `string[]` with a type of your own for testing purposes, overriding `ToString()` to display the array contents.